# How to silently get an empty string from a glob pattern with no matches

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Say I have a folder with three files:

```
foo1
foo2
bar
```

**1.**  If I run

```
list_of_files=$(print foo*)
echo $list_of_files
```

I get: `foo1 foo2`

**2.** If I run

```
list_of_files=$(print bar*)
echo $list_of_files
```

I get: `bar`

**3.** However, if I run

```
list_of_files=$(print other*)
echo $list_of_files
```

I get: `zsh: no matches found: other*` (the variable `$list_of_files` is empty though)

---

Is there a way to ask zsh to not complain if it can't match a glob expansion?

My goal is to use the mechanism above to **silently** collect a list of files that match a given glob pattern.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Turn on the `null_glob` option for your pattern with the `N` glob qualifier.

```
list_of_files=(*(N))
```

If you're doing this on all the patterns in a script or function, turn on the `null_glob` option:

```
setopt null_glob
```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23167/885) has bash and ksh equivalents.

Do not use `print` or command substitution! That generates a string consisting of the file names with spaces between them, instead of a list of strings. (See [What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/what-is-word-splitting-why-is-it-important-in-shell-programming/26672#26672))

Answer (score 20):

The better way: `for a in *(.N); do ... ; done`. The N option makes zsh deliver an empty list to for, and for will iterate zero times.

Watch out for `ls *.foo(.N)`; when ls receives an empty argument list, it lists all files instead of none. This is why I don't like NULL_GLOB (or its bash equivalent): It changes *all* the globs and easily breaks calls to e.g. ls.

Comment: Fancy seeing your answer here @arnt, this is just what I needed.

Comment: Why the `.` in `(.N)`? Other answers have `(N)` by itself, what is the difference?

Comment: The question was about files, and `.` restricts the glob to match only files.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the `NULL_GLOB` option:

> ```
>    NULL_GLOB (-G)
>           If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, delete  the
>           pattern  from  the  argument list instead of reporting an error.
>           Overrides NOMATCH.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
list_of_files=$(print other*) 2>/dev/null
```

It will redirect error output from stderr to /dev/null and it won't display.

Comment: That doesn't work at all.