# In zsh, what is the meaning of the '$==*' idiom

Tags: zsh

I have found the `$==*` idiom in several zsh solutions that I use. It seems to be equivalent to `$argv`. But I don't know how it gets interpreted. Could you explain?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of Zsh's [parameter expansions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) here applied to `$*`:

> ${=spec}
> Perform word splitting using the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during the evaluation of spec, but regardless of whether the parameter appears in double quotes; **if the ‘=’ is doubled, turn it off.** This forces parameter expansions to be split into separate words before substitution, using IFS as a delimiter. This is done by default in most other shells.

See Gilles' typically thorough answer to [What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26672/6761) for context.

Normally, `zsh` doesn't do word splitting by default, so presumably, that's to make sure `$*` is not split even when the `SH_WORD_SPLIT` option has been enabled one way or another (for instance via a `emulate sh`).

However, in most cases, you'd rather want to use `"$@"` (note the quotes which are important here) instead of `$==*`. `$==*` (like `$*` when `SH_WORD_SPLIT` is off) expands only to the **non-empty** positional parameters, while `"$@"` expands to all the positional parameters (regardless of `SH_WORD_SPLIT`, and that works in all Bourne-like shells).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks: that is much better...