# tail and bash: different output when same is expected

Tags: bash, tail, cut, command-substitution

I'm trying to sort my logs and found that single digit dates were cut incorrectly.
Now I want to either add a 0, or remove the extra space.
Prior to that, I wanted to see how to get the correct lines I want to edit.

A tail of last 3 lines:

```
$tail -3 testlog 
Wed Feb  7 23:30:59 2018 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA de:ad:be:ef:c0:fe WPA: group key handshake completed (RSN)
Wed Feb  7 23:40:59 2018 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA de:ad:be:ef:c0:fe WPA: group key handshake completed (RSN)
Wed Feb  7 23:50:59 2018 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA de:ad:be:ef:c0:fe WPA: group key handshake completed (RSN)
```

Now working my way to the script, I wrote this expecting to get the same result:

```
$ while read line; do if [ $(echo $line|cut -c7) == "b" ]; then echo $line; fi; done < testlog | tail -3
Wed Feb 7 23:30:59 2018 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA de:ad:be:ef:c0:fe WPA: group key handshake completed (RSN)
Wed Feb 7 23:40:59 2018 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA de:ad:be:ef:c0:fe WPA: group key handshake completed (RSN)
Wed Feb 7 23:50:59 2018 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA de:ad:be:ef:c0:fe WPA: group key handshake completed (RSN)
```

But with this, the extra space before the 7 is removed.
I did not expect this to happen. I'm not cutting it with my script, am I?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26661/170373), and [BashGuide: Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: Or maybe we should just mark this as a duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Comment: great link @ilkkachu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd notice the same for any other doubled (or more) spaces. [Unquoted variable expansions are followed by word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions), so once the words are split by spaces (IFS), they are reassembled with one space in-between them.

One work-around may be:

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion **that did not occur within double quotes** for word splitting.

As a concrete example, see:

```
$ line="Wed Feb  7 23:30:59"
$ echo $line
Wed Feb 7 23:30:59
```

versus:

```
$ line="Wed Feb  7 23:30:59"
$ echo "$line"
Wed Feb  7 23:30:59
```

It is well worth reading: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Comment: Example: `var='1        1'` (with many spaces, they disappear in the markup here) followed by `echo $var` and `echo "$var"`.

Comment: Excellent point, actually; it's the unquoted echo that's losing the spaces.

Comment: very clear! thanks @JeffSchaller and kusalananda