# Why is my unix basic script does not do what I try to ? (How to write abc/1 abc/2 abc/3)

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I am doing this script (with zsh, but I guess that it is not very important):

```
mylist=`seq 1 3`

for i in $mylist ; do echo "abc/$i" ; done
```

This gives :

```
abc/1

2

3
```

while I would like to see :

```
abc/1

abc/2

abc/3
```

A huge thanks to somebody that may find why it does not work/how to do.

Comment: *"with zsh, but I guess that it is not very important"* in fact, it's very important. See for example [zsh: What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/what-is-word-splitting-why-is-it-important-in-shell-programming)

Comment: @steedriver : you have a good point. Indeed, with bash, it works directly. Is there a way to make it work with zsh ?

Comment: As mentioned in [the accepted answer to the Q&A linked above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26672/65304), you should consider using an array ex. `mylist=( $(seq 1 3) )` (you can use backticks in place of `$(...)` for the command substitution if you prefer, however it is considered deprecated)

Comment: excellent, it works. thank you

Comment: ok got it. zsh does not split in general per design. very confusing

Comment: Note that you can also force the execution of your script to be in a POSIX-compatible fashion using the shebang line `#! /bin/sh` at the top of the file. Depending on your system this may run ksh/zsh/bash/dash/ash, but in any case in a mode that disables such features as the one which is causing this behavior. N.B. on most systems /bin/sh is not *completely* POSIX compatible, but usually good enough.

Comment: Quickest change to make it work with zsh could also be changing `$mylist` to `${=mylist}`. That enables word splitting on the variable expansion.

Comment: thanks both of you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep it simple:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo "abc/$i" ; done
```

OR

```
for i in $(seq 1 3); echo "abc/$i"
```

Output:

```
abc/1
abc/2
abc/3
```

Comment: sure thank you, but it was just an example : I really would like to use the "result of a unix commant with `  ...  `, not to cheat by putting by hand each value.

Comment: excellent. Thanks a lot Bruce. Unfortunately, I'm new, else I would have given you at least 1000 points for your help.

Comment: Thank you @MathieuKrisztian

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this kinda thing is via brace expansion:

```
echo abc/{1..3}
```

But naturally, since you asked for newlines, you'd need to do it like this:

```
abc_strings=( abc/{1..3} )
printf "%s\n" "${abc_strings[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this in an [online Zsh](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVMhM08hoTi1UMFQwThBgSslnys1OSNfQSkxKVlfJTMmTwkolJf6/z8A) :

```
for i in `seq 1 3` 
do
echo "abc/$i\n"
done
```

Got the following:

```
abc/1

abc/2

abc/3
```

Comment: ah yes, thanks. But if you try with a variable, this creates a problem.

Comment: In this case one does not need to create a variable, at least not in the example you have given. Defining it through the ticks (``) should suffice.

Comment: (i had changed my message meanwhile)

Comment: "this" is meaning the message of my question (for which there was a solution). There are problem with the editors : they don't print some characters. Anyway, see in my message : the inittial attempt was not working.   mylist=`seq 1 3`
for i in $mylist ; do echo "abc/$i" ; done
This gives :  abc/1
2
3