# Why can't I set IFS in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I'm on zsh. What is going on here...?

[image: 1]

It seems I just can't set the IFS; it stays on '\n' (newline, not 'n') when I investigate, but neither in my .zshenv nor .zshrc did I set it.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Another example of how weird my arrays are behaving:
[image: 2]

Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `b=($=a)` - `zsh` doesn't perform word splitting on variable expansions by default - see for example [What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26672/65304)

Comment: That worked! So weird, it always worked for me like above until today :/

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text itself ... some people here cannot view images

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not that you can't set `IFS`, it's that (unlike in bash for example) in zsh, unquoted variable expansions are not subject to "split + glob" (word splitting and filename generation). So the whole of `$a` is being assigned to the first element of `b` (which is `$b[1]`, since arrays are indexed from 1 in zsh - again different from bash).

To get bash-like behavior, you can either set zsh's `shwordsplit` shell option, or make the variable expansion word split explicitly using `$=a` in place of plain `$a`.

For a more nuanced explanation, see [What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/what-is-word-splitting-why-is-it-important-in-shell-programming)